# Installing pyzmq library for ipython through Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio-2012, ipython, pyzmq

I'm trying to install (`python setup.py install`) pyzmq to enable all the features of ipython.

Running `iptest` tells me that zmq related-code won't work correctly. I'm compiling pyzmq using visual studio 2012. My problem is that in a header file `zmq.h`. I'm getting syntax errors and the building fails.

I've tried using other compilers (creating `distutils.cfg` in the python directory using for ex. mingw32), but then the errors are even more.

The errors I'm obtaining are like missing `{` before `*` for example, but I wonder why I obtain those errors and how I can get rid of them.

Also, is it dangerous to compile packages with different compilers as for example different from the one used for the python version (msc v.1500 in my case)? I also set an env. variable to make it look like I'm using a visual studio 9.0 version as suggested in other posts: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10558328/5823060

[image: 1]

Comment: Could you please provide full error message? You should use compiler which matches your target Python version [more](https://docs.python.org/devguide/setup.html#windows)

Comment: The full error message I'm obtaining is the one in the screen shot posted.